# error : CopyWin32Resources failed with exit code 500

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am currently working on a UWP application using xamarin and everything has been going well and have now all of a sudden gotten the error below.

```
1>C:\Users\WiandeJager\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk\2.2.14\tools\CoreRuntime\Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime.targets(238,5): error : CopyWin32Resources failed with exit code 500
```

I have tried

- repairing, reinstalling and upgrading VS.
- updated Windows
- reinstalled and upgraded nuget packages

I did have some luck when repairing VS and upgrading microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk. But a soon as I make any changes no matter how insignificant, I get the same error.

Comment: It might be related with the **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform** Nuget Package. The `uwpcoreruntimesdk` is a dependency of   **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform**. Could you please try to 
 downgrade **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform**  to 6.2.12 or lower to see if this works?

Comment: Another question is that will a blank project show this error?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Roi, tried downgrading **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform** and still no luck and yes I get the same error on new and blank UWP projects.

Comment: If it happens even within a blank project, I'd suggest you report this via VS Feedback because it seems to be more related to Visual Studio itself

Comment: Turns out it was he companies anti virus blocking access to a specific file path.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling windows that always works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).